# Odd behavior with __slots__ and pickle

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently encountered a peculiar problem with slots and pickle. I have isolated the issue to the following setup:

```python
import operator
import pickle

class BinaryOperator(object):
    __slots__ = ("a", "b")

    operator = None

    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def execute(self):
        return self.operator(self.a, self.b)

class Add(BinaryOperator):
    __slots__ = ()

    operator = operator.add

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This works as intended
    add = Add(1, 1)
    assert add.execute() == 2

    # This fails:
    # Traceback (most recent call last):
    #  File "slotstest.py", line 26, in <module>
    #    assert pickle_add.execute() == 2
    #  File "slotstest.py", line 14, in execute
    #    return self.operator(self.a, self.b)
    # AttributeError: a
    pickle_add = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(add))
    assert pickle_add.execute() == 2

    # Workaround using pickling version
    pickle_add = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(add, -1))
    assert pickle_add.execute() == 2
```

This issue does not happen on Python 3, which I assume has to do with a new version of the pickle protocol.

How can I make Add compatible with the default Python 2.7 version of pickle?

Comment: Is there a reason why you choose pickle over [cpickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle)? In python3 cpickle replaced pickle. Of course that does not mean that there aren't any changes to it (from 2.7 cpickle to 3.X pickle), so it may not solve your problem.

Comment: unrelated but importing a library and the using the library name as a variable is not a great idea

Comment: @syntonym: I just used pickle in this toy example

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I would have been more careful with the naming if this wasn't a toy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support ancient pickle protocols, add to your class special methods to set and restore instance states, such as

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return self.a, self.b

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.a, self.b = state
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed solves the problem. I don't necessarily need to support ancient pickle protocols, I do however want 2.7's pickle module to work out of the box. Unless there is a way to force a newer version of the pickle protocol I consider this the correct. I would if possible like to avoid these methods, since it potentially makes subclassing more difficult.

Comment: @antennen, since in Python 2 the default protocol is the ancient `0` (ascii), if you want to support Python 2 w/o specifying a better protocol version that's what you have to do (and your pickled files will be bigger and slower to load than if you DID explicitly ask for protocol `-1` -- inevitable!).